# pointer function returning value issue

Tags: c, callback, function-pointers

I'am lately developping a C solution in wich i use function pointers to emulate callback behaviour in case of events.

i wraped my mind well around this c language capacity. Using it through out my whole program. But still i don't understand some behaviours.

I have a function in wich i return an int, lets say 4.
I put a pointer on that function and assign it to a variable in a structure.
That structure is then passed to a function where i have a global variable of my structure type that is equal to my callback's structure.

So far so good, but when i use the callback it self to retrieve the int value of 4 it returns a wrong one that look like an unitialized value, or hiting the wrong memory segment.

The callback is called in a **thread**, but it is not from a pool of threads but only one thread looping to retrieve information and pass it to the server side. So their is no concurrent access to a variable.

To give you a visual example of my implementation :

Here is the callback declaration

```
gboolean zeta_transport_is_api_secret_needed(janus_transport *plugin);
gboolean zeta_transport_is_api_secret_valid(janus_transport *plugin, const char *apisecret);
gboolean zeta_transport_is_auth_token_needed(janus_transport *plugin);
gboolean zeta_transport_is_auth_token_valid(janus_transport *plugin, const char *token);
int      zeta_transport_get_server_load();

static zeta_transport_callbacks zeta_handler_transport =
        {
                .incoming_request = zeta_transport_incoming_request,
                .transport_gone = zeta_transport_gone,
                .is_api_secret_needed = zeta_transport_is_api_secret_needed,
                .is_api_secret_valid = zeta_transport_is_api_secret_valid,
                .is_auth_token_needed = zeta_transport_is_auth_token_needed,
                .is_auth_token_valid = zeta_transport_is_auth_token_valid,
                .get_server_load = zeta_transport_get_server_load,
        };
```

The header file transport.h where i declare my function pointer :

```
struct janus_transport_callbacks {
...
        int (* const get_server_load)();
}
```

Here is me calling the init function of my transport layer :

```
janus_transport->init(&zeta_handler_transport, configs_folder);
```

The transport layer init function :

```
int janus_websockets_init(zeta_transport_callbacks *callback, const char *config_path) {
    if(g_atomic_int_get(&stopping)) {
        /* Still stopping from before */
        return -1;
    }
    if(callback == NULL || config_path == NULL) {
        /* Invalid arguments */
        return -1;
    }

    /* This is the callback we'll need to invoke to contact the gateway */
    gateway = callback;
    /* I then call the thread where the callback will be called to retrieve the integer of 4 */
    g_thread_try_new("Client_start", Client_start, NULL, NULL);
```

Once the thread is started here is how i call the "CallBack"

```
int ret = gateway->get_server_load;
      printf(KRED"Server load = %d .\n"RESET, ret);
```

And finally here is the output :

```
Server load = 4416800 .
```

I'am still fetching but i really can't see my error here for several days.

Comment: `int ret = gateway->get_server_load;` doesn't call the function - it's just an address. What about `int ret = gateway->get_server_load();`?

Comment: Did you enable all your compiler warnings? Why not?

Comment: i ll try it right away, no not all warnings i ll put -W in my makefile too. Thank you

Comment: That's not "all warnings". What you need is something like `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`, and probably `-std=c11` (or `c99` or `c89` depending on requirements).

Comment: It's working (thank you for your help)!!! with the warnings you gave me i had old-style function definition [-Wold-style-definition]
 int janus_transport_get_server_load()
So basically i was asking for the adress of the function, wich is what i was printing ?

Comment: On a conforming implementation, you should not need to enable any extra warnings. Assigning a function pointer to an integer is a constraint violation, the compiler must then give a diagnostic. I think this is a known bug in gcc.

Comment: @Lundin: Not quite. If you will `gcc` is not a conforming C compiler, but `gcc -pedantic-errors -std=c11` is.

Comment: how should i do it ? i don't really understand the issue. Should i declare it on void ? but how do i return value ?

Comment: @KerrekSB It still warns even if I remove all of -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c11. So the question is how the OP managed to disable the warning. Maybe this was a bug in an earlier version of gcc?

Comment: I guess so because i didn't made any special manipulation just a straight GCC with all the libraries. I'll update my version of GCC, and see what happens.

Comment: @Lundin: It depends on the compiler and distribution. GCC can be compiled with different defaults. GCC 6 had a major overhaul of default values for flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to *call* your callback. Change

```
int ret = gateway->get_server_load;
```

to

```
int ret = gateway->get_server_load();
//                               ^^^^
```

Comment: This must yield a compiler error/warning. Assigning a function pointer to an integer is not a valid form of "simple assignment".

Comment: on the first implementation or the second one ?